# Custom font inside "Cocoa Touch Static Library"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, static-libraries, custom-font

I am creating a framework("Cocoa Touch Static Library" ) to be used by other iOS developers.
Now i am going to use a custom font inside my framework following the steps [here](http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635).
Steps 2 is set "UIAppFonts" in Info.plist file. 
But in case of framework, Info.plist will be provided by developer ie).
So my framework users only could set "UIAppFonts" property in their application's plist file, or is there any way to set the property myself inside Framework so that every users of my framework need not to set the "UIAppFonts" property?
Please advice, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide an example plist or even write a utility that performs this setting by updating a given property list, but the users of the library will need to do something themselves, either updating the plist manually or by using your utility. You can't avoid this.

Comment: Thank you so much @H2CO3 for your quick answer, i will ask Developers to add "UIAppFonts" setting in their plist file.

Answer (score 5):

As you said, you can't set UIAppFonts from inside your static library. Depending on what you are going to use it for you might however not need it.

As a workaround you can load the fonts dynamically at any point during the app's lifetime, for example during some early called init/setup method in your static library.

See [this](http://www.marco.org/2012/12/21/ios-dynamic-font-loading) tutorial by Marco Arment, code supplied below:

```
NSData *inData = /* your decrypted font-file data */;
CFErrorRef error;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)inData);
CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
if (! CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
    CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error)
    NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
    CFRelease(errorDescription);
}
CFRelease(font);
CFRelease(provider);
```

Comment: Can you please tell what is this inData ? is it the font.ttf or otf file data or anything else.

Comment: I don't have my code in front of me but it should be the font data read from the actual ttf/otf file, yes. Did you try it and fail?

Comment: This works beautifully inside our Cocoa Touch Framework. Load the font file like this: NSString *fontPath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[ANYClassInYourFramework class]] pathForResource:@"fontfilename" ofType:@"ttf"]; NSData *fontData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fontPath];